# Profile performances of a spring scheduled task

Tags: java, spring, performance, jpa, profiling

I'm trying to profile a scheduled spring job, that make calculation on a  `ScrollableResults` iterator.

In order to profile my code I have placed several `System.nanoTime()` over ALL the code, calculating time required for each significant block code. ALL the code is covered by that time calculation, and I'm pretty sure of it.

The simplified structure of batch is the following:

```
@Scheduled(cron=CRON_EXPRESSION)
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public void calc() {
    Session session = (Session) entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    ScrollableResults entities = session.createQuery("select i.id from Entity i")
        .setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
        .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

    while (entities.next()){
        if ( ++count % 40 == 0 ) {
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.clear();
        }                   
        long idEntity = (long)entities.get(0);      
        calcService.calc(idEntity);  
    }
}
```

And here my calc service

```
@Transactional(readOnly=false, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public void calc(Long id) {
    // calculation jobs, load / saving entities from repositories
}
```

Now here a log of result that I printout on a subset of all dataset.

```
Loaded dataset
Tot Eval ds elem:  1000 Tot Eval Subentity:  2000 Req Time: 89.16532s
Tot Eval ds elem:  2000 Tot Eval Subentity:  4000 Req Time: 69.86559s
Tot Eval ds elem:  3000 Tot Eval Subentity:  6000 Req Time: 66.897255s
Tot Eval ds elem:  4000 Tot Eval Subentity:  8000 Req Time: 66.97226s
Tot Eval ds elem:  5000 Tot Eval Subentity: 10000 Req Time: 65.657s
Tot Eval ds elem:  6000 Tot Eval Subentity: 12000 Req Time: 69.23902s
Tot Eval ds elem:  7000 Tot Eval Subentity: 14000 Req Time: 75.46887s
Tot Eval ds elem:  8000 Tot Eval Subentity: 16000 Req Time: 68.46504s
Tot Eval ds elem:  9000 Tot Eval Subentity: 18000 Req Time: 65.976746s
Tot Eval ds elem: 10000 Tot Eval Subentity: 20000 Req Time: 67.081604s
LOAD DATASET SCROLLABLE RESULT: 0.02076124s
LOAD EACH ENTITY OF DATASET: 0.02628186s
MARK ALL SUBENTITYes DELETABLE: 16.105577s
FIND SUBENTITY REPORT: 17.970514s
FIND SUBENTITY REPORT2: 34.058716s
MATCH RULE FOR SUBENTITY: 0.15097496s
CALCULATE MASTER REPORT: 10.864335s
FIND SUBENTITY DEADLINE: 15.759168s
FIND SUBENTITY REPORT: 20.173891s
CALCULATE DEDALINE: 0.003906471s
SAVE DEADLINE: 22.892395s
FINISH: CLEAN UNUSED: 0.001640737s
FLUSHes / CLEANs ENTITY MANAGER: 0.009685958s
------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL TIME FROM START: 704.79083s
TOTAL TIME CALCULATED: 138.03619384765625s
UNKNOWN TIME: 566.7546997070312s
```

I also post two screenshot of VM profiling during junit test, if it could be usefull..

[image: Monitor]

[image: GC]

Here some snapshot from `iotop` related to mysql daemon:

```
Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :     824.04 K/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:    1069.55 K/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO> COMMAND                                                                                                                    
  168 be/3 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 79.97 % [jbd2/sda3-8]
 9043 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s   82.76 K/s  0.00 %  1.78 % mysqld
 2232 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s  740.09 K/s  0.00 %  1.05 % mysqld
 4302 be/4 marco       0.00 B/s 1222.34 B/s  0.00 %  0.34 % chromium-browser --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/pepperflashplugin~ppapi-flash-version=13.0.0.206 --enable-pinch [BrowserBlocking]
 2364 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.04 % [kworker/u8:0]
 1294 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mysqld

Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :     810.60 K/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:    1234.21 K/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND                                                                                                                    
  168 be/3 root        0.00 B/s    5.18 K/s  0.00 % 79.21 % [jbd2/sda3-8]
 9043 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s   80.02 K/s  0.00 %  2.52 % mysqld
 4863 be/4 marco       0.00 B/s  815.38 B/s  0.00 %  1.89 % java -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001 -Djava.library.~//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
21320 be/4 marco       0.00 B/s  815.38 B/s  0.00 %  1.56 % java -Djdk.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 -classpath /~-cachedir /home/marco/.cache/visualvm/1.3.5 --branding visualvm
29194 be/4 marco       0.00 B/s  407.69 B/s  0.00 %  1.53 % java -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001 -Djava.library.~//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
 2232 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s  721.82 K/s  0.00 %  1.29 % mysqld
18165 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.03 % [kworker/u8:1]


Total DISK READ :     407.55 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :    1735.66 K/s
Actual DISK READ:     407.55 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:    1266.82 K/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND                                                                                                                    
  168 be/3 root        0.00 B/s   10.75 K/s  0.00 % 82.54 % [jbd2/sda3-8]
 9043 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s   82.39 K/s  0.00 %  4.85 % mysqld
 2232 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s  733.11 K/s  0.00 %  2.84 % mysqld
 5255 be/4 marco     407.55 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.24 % gedit

Total DISK READ :      26.26 K/s | Total DISK WRITE :     831.29 K/s
Actual DISK READ:      26.26 K/s | Actual DISK WRITE:    1807.43 K/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND                                                                                                                    
  168 be/3 root        0.00 B/s    6.37 K/s  0.00 % 79.81 % [jbd2/sda3-8]
 2232 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s  740.56 K/s  0.00 %  2.40 % mysqld
 9043 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s   81.18 K/s  0.00 %  2.09 % mysqld
18165 be/4 root       26.26 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  1.68 % [kworker/u8:1]
 4391 be/4 marco       0.00 B/s 1629.95 B/s  0.00 %  1.29 % chromium-browser --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/pepperflashplugin~ppapi-flash-version=13.0.0.206 --enable-pinch [BrowserBlocking]
 1294 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mysqld


Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :     828.89 K/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:    1071.51 K/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND                                                                                                                    
  168 be/3 root        0.00 B/s 1221.86 B/s  0.00 % 81.63 % [jbd2/sda3-8]
 9043 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s   83.53 K/s  0.00 %  2.00 % mysqld
 2232 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s  742.18 K/s  0.00 %  1.98 % mysqld
```

and a screenshot of CPU profiler:

[image: CPU Profiler]

The problem is that `TOTAL TIME CALCULATED`, that is the SUM off all values that I collect with `System.nanoTime()` have a difference from `TOTAL TIME FROM START` of about 566 seconds (on a total of 704 :| ). That is a vary large amount of time. And I'm not able to know where this time is wasted!

Maybe that those seconds are required by spring framework in order to handle transactions / other things? In fact I have a new transaction for each dataset element.  And If yes how can I profile it?

Any help would be appreciated.

After thinking about it a little came to my mind that time I can't figure out is employed in  proxying `calcService.calc()`? Can it be?

Answer (score 2):

There is a CPU profiler with visualvm I would give that a go ( you might have to install it as a plugin ) - or if you need more indepth CPU profiling, try JProfiler

Comment: I should take a look at it, but as can be seen from the first image (if the graph can be enough), the cpu is never over 10%. Only during startup time, while spring context is initialized.

Comment: That graph shows how much of the entire CPU is being used by your program - so its no abnormal that this is low, if your program is not putting the system under too much pressure. If you expect this to be higher, then perhaps your program is spending time waiting for resources like i/o - have a look at iowait or top etc...

Your question was more like where is the time spent in my program. CPU profilers etc will show you that.

Comment: Hey man! I have updated my question... If you would like to take it a look.. thank you :)

Comment: I think I've solved. Problem is propagation=REQUIRES_NEW. Changing is to propagation=REQUIRED keep things much fast.. but is not what I want. Anyway thank you very much for your time